# Jquery form validation plugin add error border

Tags: javascript, jquery, formvalidation-plugin

I using jquery validation plugin for validate my form . All work work is fine but i want add error red border to the input field when the data is incorrect. Now show is error is work fine. but for more look i want all this error border. can help me plzz how can I add this functionality. Thanks.

```
<form action="#" id="registrainForm">
                        <h3>Create Account</h3>
                        <div class="social-container">
                            <a href="" class="social"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            <a href="" class="social"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
                            <a href="" class="social"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <span>or Be classic</span>

                        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">


                        <input id="text" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">

                        <input id="phone" name="phone" type="number" placeholder="Mobile No">

                        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">

                        <input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">

                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input id="agree" name="agree" type="checkbox" /><span class="error"></span>
                            <label for="checkbox"> I agree with <a href="" class="">Term & Conditions.</a>.
                        </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit">Register</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: not clear which plugin you are using for validation - each plugin has his own js/css and they works in differ ways. if you add interactive example in jsfiddle or repl, it will be easier to community, to help you

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: please include details directly in the question(edit question is normal practice). in the demo of plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/ i see what inputs already have red borders, input.error { border: 1px dotted red;} so still unclear what result you need

Comment: I have found the solution...on github documention. And thanks for your effort.